# Yii attach Event

Tags: php, yii

When reading YIi guide at this link: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/327/events-explained/, I have see this line:

> ...So earlier before raising the event we should have called, maybe inside the initialization method of the component, something like this:

```
$myComponent->onForestRan = array(new SomeOtherClass, 'eventHandler1');
```

I understand that this code will attach a handler to event, and the array on the left-hand side is a PHP callback function. However, what I really don't understand is its syntax, does it call a onforestRan() function (which is previously defined on $component--> see the Yii link above), if so it will not valid as it lack of $event argument. Or, if it is a callback, then I have never seen a way of using callback like this (if it is a callback where is call_user_func() or usort()..). Its syntax is really odd to me.
Could some one help me with this?
Thank so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a callback perse, but you're telling Yii what action (i.e. what function) to perform on the event.

In the example given, when `onForestRan` happens, the `eventHandler1` function from `SomeOtherClass` will be triggered.

When that page describes a callback, it's saying that whatever you assign to `$myComponent->onForestRan` needs to be a callback function.  The callback isn't executed at that point, you're just letting Yii know which callback(s) to use when the event occurs.

More details:

onForestRan is a special property of $myComponent, as [documented here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.component#component-event).  More details can be seen in [CComponent](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CComponent).  You can search [the CComponent source](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.12/framework/base/CComponent.php) for lines similar to [line 113](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.12/framework/base/CComponent.php#L113), where you can see the beginning of the logic for the special property.  This is very similar to `action*` methods in the controller.

Comment: Thank Ernie for your answer, so in: $myComponent->onForestRan = array(new SomeOtherClass, 'eventHandler1');, the onForestTan is a property of $myCompoent or it's a special code in Yii? I have read the entire CComponent base class in framework, setters, getter, __get(), __set()..., but find no clue about this kind of above code funcionality?

Comment: @petwho edited answer to add some more details.  hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

$CComponent->onWhatever is a special language construct in Yii. The "property" onWhatever is recognized in CComponent's magic __set-method and then handled as an event attachment.

Let me quote shamelessly from http://phpmaster.com/yii-under-the-hood-2/:

```
public function __set($name, $value){
    if (strncasecmp($name, "on", 2) === 0 && method_exists($this, $name)) {
        $name = strtolower($name);
        if (!isset($this->_e[$name])) {
            $this->_e[$name] = new CList();
        }
        return $this->_e[$name]->add($value);
    }
}
```

The implementation first checks if the value of $name starts with the text “on” and that a method also exists with the same name as the value. If it does, Yii assumes $value is a  representation of a callback which it needs to attach to the event defined by $name. Yii has a private member variable $_e which holds an array of callbacks keyed by event names, and it simply adds the callback to the list for the particular event key.

```
$_e => array(
    'onUserRegistered' => array(
        0 => array(object, 'sendMyEmail')
    ),
    'onSomeOtherEvent'=>array(
        0 => function(){}
        1 => ...
    )
)
```